# How do I put both a button and a Textbox in GUI window using C in Gtk+?

Tags: c, user-interface, widget, gtk

I am facing following problem while trying to create both button and text entry box using Gtk+ with C while developing a GUI program for CentOs6.6 operating system.Please help me out by suggesting a solution.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

      GtkWidget *window;
      GtkWidget *fixed;
      GtkWidget *table;
      GtkWidget *label1;
      GtkWidget *entry1;
      GtkWidget *button;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

     window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
     gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
     gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GUI Window");
     gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
     gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);

     table = gtk_table_new(3, 2, FALSE);
     gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);

     label1 = gtk_label_new("IP Address");

     gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
      GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);

     entry1 = gtk_entry_new();
     gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), entry1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
     GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);


      gtk_widget_show(table);

      gtk_widget_show(label1);

      gtk_widget_show(entry1);

      gtk_widget_show(window);

      g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


     button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("click");
 //gtk_signal_connect_object (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
                              // GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (destroy), NULL);

   // gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 0,1,1,2);
    gtk_widget_show(button); 



     fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
     gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

     button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");

      gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button, 50, 50);
      gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, 80, 35);

      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", 
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));

     g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", 
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

     gtk_widget_show_all(window);


     gtk_main();

     return 0;
    }
```

PROBLEM:

```
(finaly:18427): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkFixed to a GtkWindow, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkWindow   can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkTable.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying you can only add one widget to a GtkWindow at a time. You already are storing multiple widgets in a GtkTable and a GtkFixed. You should be able to use another container (like GtkBox) to store those two in your window.